# In The Beatles song 'IF I FELL' there's a move to D9 chord, how does it relate to the major scale?

Tags: composition

Please explain the following move to D9 :)

```
[VERSE]

     D     Em F#m     Em
If I trust in you, oh please
      A
Don't run and hide
     D    Em  F#m     Em
If I love you too, oh please
      A  
Don't hurt my pride (like her)


[MIDDLE 8]

     D9
Like her
                           G
Cause I couldn't stand the pain
    Gm                        D           A7
And I would be sad if our new love was in vain
```

Answer (score 4):

Like a lot of pop songs, the 'middle 8' starts on the IV chord. So here, in D, the middle section goes to G. D9 is a dominant form of D, including the b7 C and an E (the 9th) on top of that. It's simply a variant of D that pushes to G, the IV.

Edit - with the C and E sung, it gives a flavour - if not the whole 'chord' of C, which happens to be the IV of the G it feels like it's going in to.

Comment: Thanks! so can I assume that the first level pushes to the forth level? (I didn't study composition :/)

Comment: It's more like the verse key is D (I) and it almost modulates to G (IV). I say almost, as the song stays in D, with all the D associated chords (including D9!) but the mid section goes to G. At its end, there's the usual V (A) to return to D for the next verse. Questions about specific songs are not really allowed here, but since you ask about a particular chord sequence, it may be allowed to stay!

Comment: @Tim I think you meant "D9 is a dominant form of *G*," not *D*! :-)

Comment: @Richard - I meant that D9 is the dominant CHORD of G, but failed to phrase it well. Don't know if it's a form of anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To explain in academic theory/composition language: the D9 is a secondary dominant chord in the key of D which is being used here to tonicize the G, or temporarily make it sound more like the tonal center.  The dominant chord, the V, always has a root a fifth above the root of the tonic, so the dominant chord in D is A (or A7).  Using the dominant 7 form of the tonic to tonicize the subdominant (the IV) is a fairly common move in older pop music and hymnal music.

To me, D9 is just an extension of D7 that makes the chord a little bit more "crunchy".  If it were, say, a D9/C, in that case there might be some real ambiguity about whether the primary tonality was that C major flavor or a D7 flavor, but when the bass note is a D, a D9 and a D7 work in the same way harmonically.

Comment: The secondary dominant in key D is actually E7. A secondary dominant is the V of V. Put another way, D9 is the secondary dominant of C.

Comment: True.  Technically, "secondary dominant" refers to the dominant of the dominant.  Is there a generic term for "dominant of something other than the tonic"?  For example, what do you call the E7 in C major, often used to toncize an A minor?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it´s a tune very simple to an harmonic approach. The first chorus is rooted in D major scale and the second chorus shows a modulation to a G major scale, so the D9 chord is the V degree of G major. So, after the resolution to the new root (G), the composer use a very common tool in composition like a progression of a ladder of fifths in the chords Gm(Vth of D),then D (Vth of A), and then to A7 (Vth of D), that gives the path to the start of the song.

Comment: Check your Vs - some are IVs.

Comment: Well, if you see the Circle of Fifths in the sense of the needle of the clock G is IV of D i.e. but if do you see in the reverse way G is V of D. Remember that the intervals when are reversed always produces the number 9 (5+4).

Comment: Nearly. G will always be the IV of D, but D will always be the V of G. That's where the rule of 9 comes in. So G can never be the V of D. That's always going to be A. Count from D as number 1, and at 4 lives G. Next door at 5 (V) is A.

Answer (score 0):

The "middle 8" centres briefly on G.  Hardly worthy of being called a modulation, as it moves immediately to a Gm chord then back home to D.  But a definite excursion none the less.

If you want to establish a chord as a new base, however briefly, the standard method is to precede it with its dominant seventh chord.  (You're happy with the D9 just being a flavour of D7?)  Don't worry about it not being in the D major scale.  That sort of thing happens all the time.   It's good to know what chords are "in the scale" but we're not RESTRICTED to using those chords.

If the D9 worries you, the Gm is going to have you screaming with terror!

If you want an explanation, beyond "yes, it's common to turn the subdominant chord minor", look at the melody lines within the chord progression.  G chord includes B natural. We're heading for A7, which will get us back home to D.  So what more natural than to have a little internal melody B, Bb, A?   It could even continue down through G (part of A7 chord) and end up on F# (part of D chord).

If anyone bleats "modal interchange" ask them what that jargon actually explains.